# Wrapfigure with tikzpicture not appearing where it should

Tags: wrapfigure

I am trying to insert insets of commutative diagrams into my tex, using wrapfigure and tikz. The first commutative diagram (inside a wrapfigure environment) appears as it should, but the second commutative diagram (inside its own wrapfigure) appears much lower than it should, in a later paragraph. Here is a minimum-working-example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,arrows}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\begin{document}

%+Title
\title{Article Title}
\author{Author}
\date{\today}
\maketitle
%-Title

%+Abstract
\begin{abstract}
test
\end{abstract}
%-Abstract


\section{test}
\begin{wrapfigure}[5]{r}{0.3\textwidth}
\vspace{-18pt}
\hspace{-0pt}
\begin{tikzpicture}[description/.style={fill=white,inner sep=0pt}]
\matrix (m) [matrix of math nodes, row sep=3em,
column sep=2.5em, text height=1.5ex, text depth=0.25ex]
{ M & & N \\
& D & \\ };
%\draw[double,double distance=5pt] (m-1-1) – (m-1-3);
\path[<->]
(m-1-1) edge node[description] {$ f $} (m-1-3)
edge node[description] {$ \Phi $} (m-2-2)
(m-1-3) edge node[description] {$ \Psi $} (m-2-2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{wrapfigure}
one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one\\
\begin{wrapfigure}[5]{r}{0.3\textwidth}
\vspace{-18pt}
\hspace{-0pt}
\begin{tikzpicture}[description/.style={fill=white,inner sep=0pt}]
\matrix (m) [matrix of math nodes, row sep=3em,
column sep=2.5em, text height=1.5ex, text depth=0.25ex]
{ M & & N \\
& D & \\ };
%\draw[double,double distance=5pt] (m-1-1) – (m-1-3);
\path[<->]
(m-1-1) edge node[description] {$ f $} (m-1-3)
edge node[description] {$ \Phi $} (m-2-2)
(m-1-3) edge node[description] {$ \Psi $} (m-2-2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{wrapfigure}two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two


\end{document}
```

The second diagram appears below the "two" section, rather than to the right of it as I intend. 
What am I doing wrong?

`

Comment: insert a line break before your second `wrapfigure`

Comment: @cmhughes - Thanks! that solved it. If you write this comment as an answer (with perhaps an explanation to this "black magic" - I didn't know line breaks affect wrapfigure environments), I'll gladly accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to place either a blank line or a `\par` command before the second `wrapfigure` environment, so that a new paragraph is begun.

The `wrapfigure` environment operates on *paragraphs* of text; without the blank line (or `\par` command), the [`wrapfig`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/wrapfig) assumes that you are still within the first paragraph of text.

Here's the complete code to play with

```
% arara: pdflatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,arrows}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\begin{document}

%+Title
\title{Article Title}
\author{Author}
\date{\today}
\maketitle
%-Title

%+Abstract
\begin{abstract}
test
\end{abstract}
%-Abstract


\section{test}
\begin{wrapfigure}[5]{r}{0.3\textwidth}
\vspace{-18pt}
\hspace{-0pt}
\begin{tikzpicture}[description/.style={fill=white,inner sep=0pt}]
\matrix (m) [matrix of math nodes, row sep=3em,
column sep=2.5em, text height=1.5ex, text depth=0.25ex]
{ M & & N \\
& D & \\ };
%\draw[double,double distance=5pt] (m-1-1) – (m-1-3);
\path[<->]
(m-1-1) edge node[description] {$ f $} (m-1-3)
edge node[description] {$ \Phi $} (m-2-2)
(m-1-3) edge node[description] {$ \Psi $} (m-2-2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{wrapfigure}
one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one\\

\begin{wrapfigure}[5]{r}{0.3\textwidth}
\vspace{-18pt}
\hspace{-0pt}
\begin{tikzpicture}[description/.style={fill=white,inner sep=0pt}]
\matrix (m) [matrix of math nodes, row sep=3em,
column sep=2.5em, text height=1.5ex, text depth=0.25ex]
{ M & & N \\
& D & \\ };
%\draw[double,double distance=5pt] (m-1-1) – (m-1-3);
\path[<->]
(m-1-1) edge node[description] {$ f $} (m-1-3)
edge node[description] {$ \Phi $} (m-2-2)
(m-1-3) edge node[description] {$ \Psi $} (m-2-2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{wrapfigure}two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two


\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks. I read answers from nearly 30 persons, searched 90mins and none of them worked.. Now I found this answer and it works nice using `tikz`.

Comment: @TimS. awesome, glad it helped :)